# How can we use data augmentation for creating data set for face recognition and will the inverted faces on augmented images detected?

Tags: image-recognition, facial-recognition

I saw when browsing we can use data augmentation for creating a dataset for face recognition. The augmented images may include inverted, tilted or distorted faces. Do the model detect the face from the inverted image. When I tried my model cant able to detect any inverted or tilted faces.

Comment: Did you check your inverted image ? Look at them, be sure your data augmentation function is not producing garbage.

Comment: I used augmentor lib for augmentation

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of rotational augmentation. In fact you should augment your images at different angle as well than just inverting it. This will make your model angle agnostic.

Comment: I have done than by rotating image in smaller angles. Now model can detect the face. But is there something available to detect faces in the inverted image.